# How to show progress bar while sending mutiple image file to email

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have an `Intent` class to send multiple images to the email as an attached file. So all works fine. Only issue is that when no of images is more than 20 then it The Intent class takes time to open a particular mail client. So during that time i want to show progress bar to the user. So anyone help me to solve this out. My code for sending multiple images is shown below.

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for(int i = 0; i< NoteManager.getSingletonObject().getNoteItemCount(); i++)
{
    File imageFile = new File(m_ShareDir, NoteManager.getSingletonObject().getNote(i));
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

    Uri  imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

    uris.add(imageUri);
}

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_send_text)));
```

Comment: Simple. Use handler or async task for this issue.

Comment: Actually i haven't use threading thing at all..so  how can i implement this in my code...can u please help me to show it in my code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May it helps you

```
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(SetFrames.this,"Loading", "Please 

Wait...",true);
           new Thread() {
               public void run() {
               try {
                //do your process
               }catch(Exception e)
               {
               }
               handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
               pd.dismiss();
               }

               }.start();

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        }
        };
```

Comment: I want to use ProgressBar instead of ProgressDialog..So how that can be done

Comment: For Progress bar refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: yep its working...i simply changes this code ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(SetFrames.this,"Loading", "Please 

Wait...",true); by progressBar.setVisibility(1); Thanks.........

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  [tutorial](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/progress-bar-tutorial-for-android/). And I think here is good example for you which show the progress item [one by one.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/)
Enjoy...